# convergence in different normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

In my class lecture notes, there is such a lemma.

Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathbb F$ and $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$, $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$ be two norms on it. If there is $M > 0$ such that $$\lVert x \rVert_2 \leq M\lVert x \rVert_1$$  for all $x \in X$. Then for $S \subset X$, $S$ is closed in $(X, \lVert \cdot \rVert_1)$ if it is closed in $X, \lVert \cdot \rVert_2$.

But I feel the lemma is wrong. It should be that $S$ is closed in $(X, \lVert \cdot \rVert_2)$ if it is closed in $(X, \lVert \cdot \rVert_1)$. Consider a sequence $\{x_n\}$ that converges to $x$ in $(X, \lVert \cdot \rVert_1)$, then obviously the sequence also converges to $x$ in $(X, \lVert \cdot \rVert_2)$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if $(x_n)$ converges wrt. $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$, then it also converges wrt. $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$. But there might be sequences in $S$ that converge wrt. $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$ but not wrt. $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$, and then $S$ can be $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$-closed without being $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$-closed.